# keycloack Realm setting frontend URL works but not able to get admin console panel

Tags: keycloak

I'm relatively new to Keycloak and recently started exploring its features. I encountered an issue while setting the frontend URL for a realm. Initially, everything seemed fine as I successfully configured it to display my Keycloak welcome page on `example.com`. However, when attempting to access the realm admin console, I faced a frustrating `403 error`, and it appeared that the iframe wasn't loading properly.

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()`

This issue left me perplexed, as the available documentation on frontend URL configurations and SSL setup for these domains was quite limited. I'm currently in the process of researching and troubleshooting to find a solution, and any insights or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

403 means forbidden,are you sur you tried to access admin console with an admin account ?

Comment: So My keycloak is set on sso.example.com where I have created a realm "something" and I want everything related to this realm to happen on sso.something.com for that I setup the frontend URL in realm settings but it only shows the keycloak home page and when select admin console it shows 403.

Comment: Please provide more details of your configuration to setup your frontend URL ?